# How to Download a simple PDF File using C# and ItextSharp Library

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF report in my project. but I found a problem when I want to test my download function.

when I debugged it, i figure out that my code succeed to return a value in download  function. But there is no PDF file downloaded in my browser when I run this function.

please help me to find what is wrong with my code...
thanks

```
public byte[] CreatePdf()
{
    var Stream = new MemoryStream();
    var Doc = new Document();

    var FileName = "Coba PDF";
    Doc.AddAuthor("Awan");
    Doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    PdfPTable TableLayout = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Stream).CloseStream = false;
    Doc.Open();

    Doc.Add(Header(TableLayout));

    Doc.Close();
    var file = Stream.ToArray();

    return file;
}

private PdfPTable Header(PdfPTable tableHeader)
{
    var KMBDLogo = Image.GetInstance(this.Path + "\\wwwroot\\Assets\\logo.png");
    KMBDLogo.ScaleToFit(100, 50);
    tableHeader.SetWidths(new[] { 20,80 });
    tableHeader.WidthPercentage = 100;

    //set isi setiap cell
    tableHeader.AddCell(new PdfPCell(KMBDLogo)
    {
        Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER,
        Rowspan = 3
    });

    tableHeader.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("BLABLABLAB", this.FontTitle))
    {
        Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER,
        Colspan = 3,
        VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
    });
    return tableHeader;
}

public FileResult Download(byte[] wow)
{
    return File(wow, "application/pdf", "WowBanget.pdf");
}


       This is my OnGet() function : 
Public void OnGet()
{

PDFService Pdf = new PDFService();
 Pdf.download(pdf.createpdf());

   }
```

Comment: In `Download()`, you do not call the `CreatePdf()` that supposedly creates the PDF?

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete code. Actually i’d called it in my OnGer() function. When first load the page.

Comment: The question remains, why your Download endpoint is taking a byte array parameter and returning the same to the client. Delete wow and just return whatever you created from OnGer()